# Scroll to error in react-final-form querySelector doesn't work first time?

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I need to add scroll to first error in form. I found few solutions:

1. [extra package](https://github.com/final-form/final-form-focus) - doesn't work
2. Code from discussion [here](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/39)

   ```
   <FormSpy
     subscription={{ submitFailed: true }}
     onChange={() => {
       const el = document.querySelector('.error')
       if (el) {
           el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
       }
     }}
   />
   ```

My problem is that second case works only second time. Before I submit first time `error` className doesn't exist yet, it appears only after submit, and `el` is `null`. But second and next times it works all the time, if I not remove error className from render.

How can I solve it?

Comment: <FormSpy
  subscription={{ submitFailed: true }}
  onChange={() => {
setTimeout(() => {}, 0)
  }}
/>

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found few issues in my project and made [package](https://github.com/final-form/final-form-focus) to work. First issue is that this packages works only with form submit and doesn't work with button click, another issue is that my button component didn't have *name* tag, so I needed to add it. Now it works